# com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod$MethodException

Tags: vaadin

I have two classes DocumentManagertwoApplication.java and DocumentEditor.java (code is below). I need some help figuring out this error I get when I click on the 'Edit' button

com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod$MethodException: Invocation of method buttonClick in com.example.documentmanagertwo.DocumentmanagertwoApplication$1 failed.
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:532)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:164)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.fireEvent(AbstractComponent.java:1219)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:550)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button.changeVariables(Button.java:217)
    at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.changeVariables(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:1455)
    at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.handleVariableBurst(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:1399)
    at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.handleVariables(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:1318)
    at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.doHandleUidlRequest(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:763)
    at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.CommunicationManager.handleUidlRequest(CommunicationManager.java:296)
    at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.service(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:501)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/example/documentmanagertwo/DocumentEditor
    at com.example.documentmanagertwo.DocumentmanagertwoApplication$1.buttonClick(DocumentmanagertwoApplication.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:512)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.documentmanagertwo.DocumentEditor
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1711)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
    ... 33 more

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
DocumentManagertwoApplication code below:

```
FilesystemContainer docs = new FilesystemContainer (new File("C:\\Users\\MYRA\\Desktop\\Docx4java\\docs"));
Table selector = new Table (null, docs);
Label viewer = new Label ("Select a doc", Label.CONTENT_RAW);
Button edit = new Button ("edit");


@Override
public void init() {
    final Window mainWindow = new Window("Documentmanagertwo Application", new VerticalSplitPanel());
    VerticalLayout lo = new VerticalLayout();
    Label label = new Label("Hello Vaadin user");
    mainWindow.addComponent(label);
    mainWindow.addComponent(selector);
    lo.addComponent(viewer);
    lo.addComponent(edit);
    mainWindow.addComponent(lo);
    setMainWindow(mainWindow);

    edit.addListener(new Button.ClickListener (){


        private static final long serialVersionUID = -3024072268109652498L;

        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event ) {

            Window dialog = new Window ("Edit Selected", 
                    new DocumentEditor(viewer.getPropertyDataSource()));
            dialog.setModal(true);
            mainWindow.addWindow (dialog);

        }


    });

    selector.setImmediate(true);
    selector.setSizeFull();
    selector.setSelectable(true);
    selector.addListener(new Property.ValueChangeListener()  {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
            viewer.setPropertyDataSource(new TextFileProperty((File) selector.getValue()));
        }

    });
}
```

}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
DocumentEditor.java code below:
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
@AutoGenerated
private AbsoluteLayout mainLayout;

@AutoGenerated
private Button button_1;

@AutoGenerated
private RichTextArea richTextArea_1;

/*- VaadinEditorProperties={"grid":"RegularGrid,20","showGrid":true,"snapToGrid":true,"snapToObject":true,"movingGuides":false,"snappingDistance":10} */



/*- VaadinEditorProperties={"grid":"RegularGrid,20","showGrid":true,"snapToGrid":true,"snapToObject":true,"movingGuides":false,"snappingDistance":10} */

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 2788446877665474591L;
/**
 * The constructor should first build the main layout, set the
 * composition root and then do any custom initialization.
 *
 * The constructor will not be automatically regenerated by the
 * visual editor.
 */
public DocumentEditor(Property document) {
    buildMainLayout();
    setCompositionRoot(mainLayout);

    // TODO add user code here
    richTextArea_1.setPropertyDataSource(document);
    richTextArea_1.setWriteThrough(false);

    button_1.addListener(new Button.ClickListener()  {


        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event ) {
            richTextArea_1.commit();
            getApplication().getMainWindow().removeWindow(getWindow());
        }
    });

}

@AutoGenerated
private AbsoluteLayout buildMainLayout() {
    // common part: create layout
    mainLayout = new AbsoluteLayout();
    mainLayout.setImmediate(false);
    mainLayout.setWidth("100%");
    mainLayout.setHeight("100%");
    mainLayout.setMargin(false);

    // top-level component properties
    setWidth("100.0%");
    setHeight("100.0%");

    // richTextArea_1
    richTextArea_1 = new RichTextArea();
    richTextArea_1.setImmediate(false);
    richTextArea_1.setWidth("572px");
    richTextArea_1.setHeight("360px");
    mainLayout.addComponent(richTextArea_1, "top:0.0px;left:-2.0px;");

    // button_1
    button_1 = new Button();
    button_1.setCaption("Save");
    button_1.setImmediate(false);
    button_1.setWidth("-1px");
    button_1.setHeight("-1px");
    mainLayout.addComponent(button_1, "top:360.0px;left:500.0px;");

    return mainLayout;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the exception is 
`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.documentmanagertwo.DocumentEditor`

This  means the JVM cannot find or load the given class.

Does DocumentEditor import any classes or paths from libraries that are not on the classpath?
This is often the cause of this problem.

Is the compiled class in the classpath? I'd try cleaning and rebuilding my project.